# Font family declaration in creatjs

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

What is the correct way to declare font family in *createjs*?
For now I am declaring as:

```
this.text = new cjs.Text("some text", "bold 14px HeleveticaLtStd-LightCond", "#333333")
```

This is giving some default font in output.

What am I doing wrong? Please suggest as I am new to createjs.

Comment: This looks correct. You will have to ensure the font is loaded before you update the stage. If the Ticker is running, and it isn't working, it is possible the font name is wrong.

Comment: `HeleveticaLtStd-LightCond` doesn't look like a standard font, do you have it in the font css-file? If not, you can include it as described in this link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: thanks for the font face suggestion , actually i had added it before but for some reason it was not working with a different syntax finally it works.